# Byobu creates new icon in unity launcher

Tags: unity, byobu

I have locked the byobu icon in my unity menu. When I click it I would expect to have a window for this icon.

But this does not happen. What actually happens is when I click it for the first time, it opens a Terminal window, with it's own, new icon in the menu (so now I have an byobu icon which looks like is not started, and an unwanted terminal icon). If I click the byobu icon a second time, it opens a new terminal window.

I have this problem since I got a new laptop (ubuntu 15.10). On my old laptop it works as expected (ubuntu 14.04 LTS).

How can I fix this?

Edit:
From the comments:

The Exec line in /usr/share/applications/byobu.desktop:

```
Exec=env TERM=xterm-256color byobu
```

Comment: what does `Exec` line in `/usr/share/applications/byobu.desktop` file tell you ?

Comment: @Serg Exec=env TERM=xterm-256color byobu

Comment: hmm, it's the default. Change it to `Exec=gnome-terminal -e byobu` See if that helps

Comment: @Serg Thanks, but no change (actually, now it shows another terminal for a sec. then closes that and that opens a new terminal with byobu. Turning terminal to false in the file fixed that...)

Comment: Right, if `Terminal=true` it will spawn a terminal window, and tell it to run whatever `Exec=` specifies. The idea there was to spawn byobu in default terminal emulator . . . mmm, which is by default `gnome-terminal` ( so I messed up there).  Try `xterm -e byobu`. If that's still an issue, it's not a terminal-dependend bug, but something else

Comment: @Serg, Nope, doesn't work either. Also, on my old pc, where everything is fine, the .desktop file was the same as on my new one. So it should be possible to get it working without changing that file. (But if changing that file fixes it, I am happy too!)

Comment: thing is, that `Exec` line is not out of the ordinary, that's default. My suspicion was is that it's different in 15.10 somehow.  So , we've ruled out it's  not terminal dependent, it's not dependent on the icon file/shortcut file (that's what `.desktop` files really are).  At this moment, I don't know. I guess someone else might know better. Otherwise , I see it as a bug worth reporting

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a [known bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/bamf/+bug/1503418) in BAMF, the window-matching framework that's used by Unity. I think they are still working on a SRU (Stable Release Update)—I seem to have byobu `5.97-0ubuntu1` on 15.10, and the fix is in `5.98-0ubuntu1` or later.

There is a workaround in comment #2 if you don't mind Unity associating *all* gnome-terminal windows with the Byobu icon.

Answer (score 0):

To those that have this problem in ubuntu19.10 with unity still. This is the desktop file I am using now and that works:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Name=Byobu Terminal
Comment=Advanced Command Line and Text Window Manager
Icon=byobu
Exec=gnome-terminal --class=byobu -- byobu
Type=Application
StartupWMClass=byobu
Categories=GNOME;GTK;Utility;
X-GNOME-Gettext-Domain=byobu
```

It neatly puts the byobu window under the byobu icon. It works because of the "StartupWMClass" and the "--class=" having the same value. If you open a new terminal window that does not have the --class=byobu it does not stack under the same icon.